# Label text is not updating in tableview children in titanium android.but work's in IOS

Tags: android, imageview, titanium, label, tableview

I have tried to update/change the lebel in android using titanium.but the value is not showing on the text .but am getting the updated value in the alert.But the ios is working perfectly.

```
 var itemcounttext = Ti.UI.createLabel({
 top: 5,
 color: "#000000",
 left:10,
 text:data[i].itemCount,
 width: Ti.UI.SIZE,
 height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
 });
var additem = Ti.UI.createImageView({
image: "/images/plus.jpg",
top: 5,
width: Ti.UI.SIZE,
left:10,
height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
});
adddeleteitemview.add(additem);
additem.addEventListener('click', function(e)
    {
        var item=e.source.getParent();
        squantity = e.source.squantity;
            squantity = Number(squantity) + 1;
            item.children[1].text = squantity;
            alert(item.children[1].getText());
```

Here am getting the alert with correct updated value.But the it's not showing in the label. Can you give me a idea to resolve this problem in android.

**EDIT:**

From VRK comment i have tried this also.But it's not working.but am getting the alert correctly.

```
item.children[1].setText(squantity);
```

**EDIT:**

I tried with jsplaine answer.But i can't get the solution. Here i have created the tableview .in this tableview row we are creating the view.in that view i have adidng the additem,itemcounttext values.if we are clicking the additem means need to change the itemcounttext value.This is a flow.

like below screenshot is children view of my app tableview:

```
productname

remove     itemcount   add
image      text        image
```

this three image,text,image values are added in one view.That's why am adding the code for getting the parent view while clicking add image:

```
var item=e.source.getParent();
```

here am getting the parent.also am wrote the below code for getting the label for this view:

```
item.children[1].text
```

If am clicking the add image, am getting the label value is incresed by 1 correctly .am verified with this code `alert(item.children[1].getText())`;.
but the updated value is not showing.This is my exact doubt.

**EDIT:**

This is my full source code.

```
 dataArray = [];       
 $.ViewCartItemslist_total_value.text = totalamount;
 for( var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
```

//creating the tableviewrow

```
 var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
 layout : 'horizontal',
 top:5,
 width: "100%",
 height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
 });
 row.add(Ti.UI.createImageView({
 image: data[i].image,
 top: 5,
 width: '50',
 height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
 }));
row.add(Ti.UI.createLabel({
text: data[i].name,
 top: 5,
 width: 180,
 font: { fontSize: '10dp' },
 color: '#040404',
 wordWrap: true,
 height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
 ellipsize: true
 }));
```

//creating the view inside of each every row of tableviewrow

```
 var adddeleteitemview = Ti.UI.createView({
 width: Ti.UI.SIZE,
 height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
 layout : 'horizontal',
 left:10,
 borderColor:"gray",
 borderRadius:"10"
 });
 var removeitem = Ti.UI.createImageView({
 image: "/images/minus.jpg",
 top: 5,
 left:10,
 width: "15%",
 height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
 });
 adddeleteitemview.add(removeitem);
 var itemcounttext = Ti.UI.createLabel({
 top: 5,
 color: "#000000",
 left:10,
 text:data[i].itemCount,
 textAlign:'center',
 width: "15%",
 height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
 });
 adddeleteitemview.add(itemcounttext);

 var additem = Ti.UI.createImageView({
 image: "/images/plus.jpg",
 top: 5,
 width: "15%",
 left:10,
 squantity : data[i].itemCount,
 spprice :data[i].itemPrice,
 height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
 });
 adddeleteitemview.add(additem);
 additem.addEventListener('click', function(e)
    {
        var item=e.source.getParent();
        spprice = e.source.spprice;
        if(item.children[1].getText() == e.source.squantity){
        squantity = e.source.squantity;
          totalqty = Number(totalqty) + Number(1);
            $.ViewCartItemslist_header_cart.text = totalqty;
            totalamount = Number(totalamount) + Number((spprice));
            squantity = Number(squantity) + 1;
            item.children[1].text = squantity;
           // item.itemcounttext.text = squantity;
          // item.itemcounttext.setText(squantity);
           // item.children[1].setText(squantity);
            alert(item.children[1]+" "+item.children[1].getText());
            $.ViewCartItemslist_total_value.text = totalamount;
            totalprice = Number(spprice) * squantity;
        }
           else {
                squantity = item.children[1].getText();
            totalqty = Number(totalqty) + Number(1);
            $.ViewCartItemslist_header_cart.text = totalqty;
            totalamount = Number(totalamount) + Number((spprice));
            squantity = Number(squantity) + 1;
            item.children[1].text = squantity;
            item.children[1].setText(squantity);
            alert(item.children[1].getText());
            $.ViewCartItemslist_total_value.text = totalamount;
            totalprice = Number(spprice) * squantity;
            }
           });
       row.add(adddeleteitemview); 

      dataArray.push(row);
    row.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    });
    $.ViewCartItemstableView.setData(dataArray);
     }
```

Comment: have you tried item.children[1].setText(squantity);

Comment: @VRK yes tried .But it's also not working.

Comment: I see itemcounttext defined, but it's not referenced anywhere else.  In this code, it's not a parent or child of anything else defined there.  Why not make itemcounttext a property of additem?  Then you could additem.itemcounttext.setText(whatever).

Comment: Are you testing on emulator, simulator or a real device ? I have tried to reproduce your bug but .. it just work fine for me on both simulator and device.

Comment: @KtorZ yes i have testing with all simulator ,emulator and real android device(micromax and sony).but i have facing this issue on these devices.

Comment: @KrishnaVeni well... Could you expose a full workable example so that we can try to reproduce your bug ? (I mean, please name your snippets with corresponding files, and write down anything that take part to the process).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of walking the parent/child tree, just make itemcounttext a property of additem:

```
var itemcounttext = Ti.UI.createLabel({
 top: 5,
 color: "#000000",
 left:10,
 text:data[i].itemCount,
 width: Ti.UI.SIZE,
 height: Ti.UI.SIZE
});

var additem = Ti.UI.createImageView({
 image: "/images/plus.jpg",
 top: 5,
 width: Ti.UI.SIZE,
 left:10,
 height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
});

additem.countTextLabel = itemcounttext;

adddeleteitemview.add(additem);

additem.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
 var item=e.source;
 var squantity = e.source.squantity;
 squantity = Number(squantity) + 1;
 item.countTextLabel.setText(squantity);
 alert(item.countTextLabel.getText());
});
```

Comment: I still don't see itemcounttext as a parent or child of additem in your code.   But that's OK.  Instead of `item.countTextLabel.setText(squantity);`, Just do `itemcounttext.setText(squantity);`.   itemcounttext is in the scope of your event listener, doesn't need to be passed to it.

Comment: it's also tried.not working...itemcounttext is a sibling of a additem.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for the better part of an afternoon. Hopefully this helps someone.

In my case I had a tableview with just 1 custom row by design. Clicking the row allowed me to choose a new value (name and description) from a different tableview, and then update the first tableview custom row data with the newly selected values.

For the problematic tableview, I was using setData, but the custom rows are fairly complex so I didn't want to have to rebuild one row of one of these complex rows. Here is what worked for me... I just updated the labels in the data array that are contained in a wrapper view that is contained in the row. This way rather than rebuilding all of the data array from scratch, I was able to modify the array and then just set data again.
                                                                dataStatus[0].children[0].children[0].text = sice.row.name;
dataStatus[0].children[0].children[1].text = sice.row.statusdescription;
tableviewStatus.setData(dataStatus);

I only have 1 row so dataStatus[0] addresses that row. Then the first child is the wrapper view, and I counted my layout and the 1st and 2nd child of the wrapper are the labels I needed to update. Then after I modified the array, I just redid setData. Worked like a champ.

Hope it helps someone.